# search function for laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

guys somehow this search function not working.i been following a tutorial for search function in laravel 5.8 can you help me im still a total beginner at this. if i ask this question wrong please forgive me.. this is my first time asking... and if im being rude im truly sorry...

**pegawaicontroller.php**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    // menangkap data pencarian
    $search = $request->search;

    // mengambil data dari table pegawai sesuai pencarian data
    $pegawai = DB::table('pegawais')
    ->where('nama_pegawai','LIKE',"%".$search."%")
    ->paginate();

        // mengirim data pegawai ke view index
    return view('pegawai.index',['pegawais' => $pegawai]);

    }
```

**pegawai.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pegawai extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['kategori', 'jabatan', 'nama_pegawai', 'alamat', 'gambar_pegawai', ];
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('template.adminlte')

@section('content')
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Menu Pegawai</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">pegawai</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>

<form action="/pegawai/search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Cari Pegawai .." value="{{ old('search') }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

 <section class="content">
 <div class="container-fluid">

 
 <a href="{{ route('pegawai.create') }}" class="btn btn-info btnsm float-right">
 <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Tambah Menu</i>
 </a><br><br>



 @if ($message = Session::get('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success martop-sm">
        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
    </div>
 @endif
    <table class="table martop-sm">
    <thead> 
        <th>No</th>
        <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
        <th>Kategori</th>
        <th>Jabatan Pegawai</th>
        <th>Nama pegawai</th>
        <th>Alamat</th>
        <th>Foto Pegawai</th>
        <th>Aksi</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 @foreach ($pegawais as $key => $pegawai)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $pegawais->firstItem() + $key }}</td>
        <!-- <td>{{ $pegawai->id }}</td> -->
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->kategori }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->jabatan }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->nama_pegawai }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}">{{ $pegawai->alamat }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('pegawai.show', $pegawai->id)}}"><img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $pegawai->gambar_pegawai) }}" alt="" width="100"></a></td>
        <td>
        <form action="{{ route('pegawai.destroy', $pegawai->id) }}" method="post"> 
        {{csrf_field()}} {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            <a href="{{ route('pegawai.edit', $pegawai->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Ubah</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapusnya?');">Hapus</button>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ $pegawais -> links() }}
    </div>
    </section>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**web.php (my route)**

```
Route::get('/pegawai')->name('pegawai.index')->uses('pegawaicontroller@index');
Route::get('/pegawai/search')->uses('pegawaicontroller@search');
```

Expectation:

> Function Working As Intended

Reality:

> **404 PAGE NOT FOUND**

Comment: what's the generated url for form action??

Comment: can you provide user model in question 
 action="/pegawai/search"  this is not right way to define url  
action="{{url('/pegawai/search')}}"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply i been busy. the model i use i pegawai.php and it can be seen in there have edit it.

Comment: the generated url is http://localhost:8000/pegawai/search?search=goro (goro is the name i want to search)

Comment: welp no i got a new problem completely different than this after fixing the problems... im gonna close the page now... FYI:its the search function that not working so i change it from /pegawai/search to just search.